# Grouping in an empty object

Tags: mesh

I can group several objects using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
However, the "main" object is the last selected object.
I find this a bit distracting.
Is there a way to group my objects in an empty object?

I would like to be able to parent my objects like this:

[image]

I was not really able to do that, so I added a plane as the main-object.
Is there a way to do that without having to add an additional, superflouos element?

Comment: You can *parent* several objects using `Ctrl`+`P`. So are you grouping them or parenting ?

Comment: @MrZak I have added a screenshot to show what I want to do. I had to insert a new element (I have simply chosen a plane) in order to create a main object. I would like to ask if it is possible to do this without having to add such a placeholder object.

Comment: I think I found the solution myself. In this case it would be smarter to use Groups.

Comment: Usually this is done by creating an *empty* and parenting all the objects you want to be grouped to the empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution myself. In this case it would be smarter to use Groups.

Comment: I think that is the answer if you want to keep these independent. It's common to just use an **Empty** as well.